# Styled-Component Button href/onclick not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I'm learning JS/trying to get a website up using gatsby and need to use buttons and have been using styled-components.

the buttons show up and when I hover over  it  does turn yellow but I  i dont get a grabber mouse when I hover nor when I click do the buttons open up google

please help :)

I tried just using an href attribute like https://www.styled-components.com/ was used on the main website

```
<Button
     href="https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components"
     target="_blank"
     rel="noopener"
     primary
   >
```

but didn't work either

here is the styled button component

```
const Button = styled.button`
  border: none;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 2% 25% 3% 25%;
  z-index:5;

  background-color: ${props => props.theme.grey};
  color: ${props => props.theme.offWhite};
  &:hover {
    background: ${props => props.theme.yellow};
    color: ${props => props.theme.grey};
  }
```

and here is the offending code

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');"> work</button>
<Button click={() => 'https://www.google.com';}}>pleaseWork </Button>
```

Comment: button does not have a href attribute. you need to use anchor tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `styled.a` not `styled.button` to have access to `href` prop.

Now you can add Styled Component like the website:

```
<Button
     href="https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components"
     target="_blank"
     rel="noopener"
     primary
   >
```

[See this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-cdn-ip7sz)